# Is it possible to use javascripts fillRect() function to fill from the centre

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using the fillRect function in js but it seems like it coordinates inputted seem to be located at the top left of the rectangle as opposed to the centre, as I would prefer. Is there a function or a workaround possible for this.

Comment: There are not any way. You can calculate you center coordinates like width / 2 and height / 2 and use it like a starting point. But I really don't recommend this way, better use default values

Comment: The workaround is to figure out where the center would be and reverse-calculate where the top left should be based on the dimensions of your rectangle

Comment: I wonder why even you want to do such thing?

Comment: @nAviD there are many many situations where you know where the center of something should be before anything else.

Comment: Oh sorry I read your question again. At first I thought you want to fill it starting from center !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp) uses example

```
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```

Which puts a 150x100 rectangle with its top left at 20,20

But if you want it centered at 20,20 instead, you'd subtract half the width from the x, and half the height from the y,

```
ctx.fillRect(20-(150/2), 20-(100/2), 150, 100);
```

I've made a small jsfiddle with a red dot showing the center

https://jsfiddle.net/82xzum0f/

You can write your own function that does the logic for you if you need to do it repeatedly,

```
function drawCenterRec(ctx, x, y, width, height) {
      // change x and y by half of the width and half of the height
      // then draw a rectangle on the context.
}
```